# Laravel 5 - Form binding with One To One relashionship

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.0, and I want to edit a user account , so the users have `phone` as a one to one relationship.

User model :

```
public function phone()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
}
```

Phone model :

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

So, how to show phone number in edit form ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in your phone model you have a field called number and from the controller your using you can retrieve a User and pass to the form template. Then on the form you would access the number this way.

```
$user->phone->number
```